# PTIJ: Does Chukot Hagoyim and Dina D’malchuta Dina apply on planet of the apes

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Does the usual Halacha  of following the secular laws of non-Jews and prohibition against following non-Jewish customs  apply on planet of the apes?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: `the planet of the apes` is a weird way of referring to Earth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is still a difference for Torah-dik Jews.

Even the elderly who are moving there for a quiet retirement, stand apart.

As [Koheles Rabbah 1:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Kohelet_Rabbah.1.2.1?ven=The_Sefaria_Midrash_Rabbah,_2022&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes:

> רַבִּי שְׁמוּאֵל בַּר רַב יִצְחָק מַתְנֵי לָהּ בְּשֵׁם רַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן בֶּן אֶלְעָזָר, שִׁבְעָה הֲבָלִים שֶׁאָמַר קֹהֶלֶת כְּנֶגֶד שִׁבְעָה עוֹלָמוֹת שֶׁאָדָם רוֹאֶה...הִזְקִין, הֲרֵי הוּא כְּקוֹף. הֲדָא דְּתֵימַר בְּעַמֵּי הָאָרֶץ, אֲבָל בִּבְנֵי תוֹרָה כְּתִיב (מלכים א א, א): וְהַמֶּלֶךְ דָּוִד זָקֵן, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוּא זָקֵן, מֶלֶךְ.
>
> Rabbi Shmuel bar Rav Yitzḥak taught it in the name of Rabbi Shimon ben Elazar: The seven vanities [havalim] that Koheles mentioned correspond to the seven worlds that a person sees...When he grows old, he is like a monkey. That is stated regarding the common people; however, regarding Torah personalities, it is written: “King David was old” – even though he was old, he was a king.